# Push multiple objects with dynamic data into a DTO and return it

Tags: c#, .net-core

So I'm trying to use a DTO to reshape and return data, it's not working because I'm trying to push in an array of objects (as an `IQueryable` - which I don't think works) into the DTO, I'm also trying to push in dynamic data into one of the properties, as seen below in the 'hasCurrentUserLiked' property. I need to figure out How to change the objects from `IQueryable`, into actual objects so they can all be pushed into the DTO and the dynamic data can be worked out.

This is the code

```
    public async Task<PagedList<UserPhoto>> GetSpecificFeed(UserParams userParams)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == userParams.u);
        var userId = user.Id;
        var photos = _context.UserPhotos;
        var followerIds = _context.Follows.Where(x => x.FollowerId == userId).Select(x => x.FollowingId).ToList();
        var feeds = _context.UserPhotos.Where(x => followerIds.Contains(x.UserId)).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded);

        // this doesn't work because 'feeds' is an IQueryable, not an object
        var like = await hasCurrentUserLiked(user.Id, feeds.id);

        // this has the same problem as above
        var feedsToReturn = new FeedsForReturnDto
        {
            Id = feeds.Id,
            PhotoUrl = feeds.photoUrl,
            Username = feeds.Username,
            Description = feeds.Description,
            DateAdded = feeds.DateAdded,
            IsImage = feeds.IsImage,
            hasCurrentUserLiked = like,
            Likes = feeds.Likes
        }

        return await PagedList<UserPhoto>.CreateAsync(feedsToReturn, userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);
    }
```

I thought that I might be able to get each image.id in a similar way the 'followerIds' are worked out but I couldn't figure out how to get this to work

[EDIT]

As per Enas Osamas answer, I've changed the code to this and I've debugged it, feedsToReturn has the correct info, so it is doing what its supposed to do. The problem I'm having now is that I'm unable to return it as it can't convert the IEnumerable to an IQueryable. I tried adding an explicit cast but that didn't work, I also tried removing the PagedList, and replacing the type  to  but this didn't work. My  is an IQueryable which might be the problem, I tried changing that to an IEnumerable but this would mess up the code in other places.

This is my new code (still returning 'feeds' instead of 'feedsToReturn', will change when it works)

```
    public async Task<PagedList<UserPhoto>> GetSpecificFeed(UserParams userParams)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == userParams.u);
        var userId = user.Id;
        var photos = _context.UserPhotos;
        var followerIds = _context.Follows.Where(x => x.FollowerId == userId).Select(x => x.FollowingId).ToList();
        var feeds = _context.UserPhotos.Where(x => followerIds.Contains(x.UserId)).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded);

        var feedToReturn = feeds.AsEnumerable().Select(feed => new FeedsForReturnDto
        {
            Id = feed.Id,
            PhotoUrl = feed.photoUrl,
            Username = feed.Username,
            Description = feed.Description,
            DateAdded = feed.DateAdded,
            IsImage = feed.IsImage,
            hasCurrentUserLiked = hasCurrentUserLiked(user.Id, feed.Id),
            Likes = feed.Likes
        });

        return await PagedList<UserPhoto>.CreateAsync(feeds, userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);
    }
```

I also tried changing some of the types around and this is what I came up with. The problem here is this:

'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<cartalk.api.Dtos.feeds.FeedsForReturnDto>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Collections.IEnumerable>'

and this problem is with the 'feedsToReturn' in the last line

```
    public async Task<PagedList<IEnumerable>> GetSpecificFeed(UserParams userParams)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == userParams.u);
        var userId = user.Id;
        var photos = _context.UserPhotos;
        var followerIds = _context.Follows.Where(x => x.FollowerId == userId).Select(x => x.FollowingId).ToList();
        var feeds = _context.UserPhotos.Where(x => followerIds.Contains(x.UserId)).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded);

        var feedToReturn = feeds.AsEnumerable().Select(feed => new FeedsForReturnDto
        {
            Id = feed.Id,
            PhotoUrl = feed.photoUrl,
            Username = feed.Username,
            Description = feed.Description,
            DateAdded = feed.DateAdded,
            IsImage = feed.IsImage,
            hasCurrentUserLiked = hasCurrentUserLiked(user.Id, feed.Id),
            Likes = feed.Likes
        });

        return await PagedList<IEnumerable>.CreateAsync(feedToReturn, userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);
    }
```

PagedList code

```
        public static async Task<PagedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source,
            int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
        }
```

[EDIT]

This is the hasCurrentUserLiked function, it works here

```
  public bool checkCurrentUserLiked(int currentUserId, int imageId)
    {
        var doesCurrentUserLike = _context.PhotoLikes.Where(x => x.LikerId == currentUserId && x.ImageId == imageId);

        var value = true;

        if (doesCurrentUserLike == null)
        {
            value = false;
        }
        else
        {
            value = true;
        }

        return value;
    }
```

Comment: What datatype is hasCurrentUserLiked in FeedsForReturnDto?

Comment: It's a boolean that says whether the current user has liked this image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
feeds.AsEnumerable().Select(feed => new FeedsForReturnDto
        {
            Id = feed.Id,
            PhotoUrl = feed.photoUrl,
            Username = feed.Username,
            Description = feed.Description,
            DateAdded = feed.DateAdded,
            IsImage = feed.IsImage,
            hasCurrentUserLiked = hasCurrentUserLiked(user.Id, feed.id),
            Likes = feed.Likes
        });
```

This would return an IEnumerable containing all the feeds mapped to your DTO after being enumerated to avoid performing operations against the database

[EDIT]

you can maybe do a left join with the _context.PhotoLikes. 
Like this

```
feeds.GroupJoin(_context.PhotoLikes,
                f => new { Id = f.Id, UserId = user.Id },
                p => new { Id = p.ImageId, UserId = p.LikerId },
                (f, p) => new { feed = f, photoLike = p })
            .SelectMany(f => f.photoLike.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (f, p) => new FeedsForReturnDto
                {
                    Id = f.feed.Id,
                    PhotoUrl = f.feed.photoUrl,
                    Username = f.feed.Username,
                    Description = f.feed.Description,
                    DateAdded = f.feed.DateAdded,
                    IsImage = f.feed.IsImage,
                    hasCurrentUserLiked = p != null,
                    Likes = feed.Likes
                });
```

Just note that in this part

```
f => new { Id = f.Id, UserId = user.Id },
p => new { Id = p.ImageId, UserId = p.LikerId },
```

the datatypes of properties in both objects must match or it won't compile

Comment: I've updated the question to match this answer, please take a look

Comment: Without the hasCurrentUserLiked function you can just remove the AsEnumerable() call and the this would return as IQueryable. Depending on what that function does you can maybe update this field after you've casted your code to a the PagedList with another Select() or if what you're doing in that function can be translated to a query against the database you can leave the call and just remove AsEnumerable().
Try it and let me know if I can help you

Comment: Removing the AsEnumerable worked, the function is supposed to check whether the 'Like' exists in the database, it is however throwing me an error as I can't figure out how to get it to check if the 'Like' exists. I've updated my question with more info.

Comment: I updated the answer. I didn't compile the code because I have only a snippet. I wrote this query with what I could gather from the code you've shared. it might need some tweaking depending on the actual implementation of the objects. try it and let me know